# Mapping a flattened parent/child list

Tags: mapstruct

I've got a flattened parent/child object like so:

```
class Flattened {
  int parentId;
  int childId;
  int someParentProperty1, someParentProperty2, ...;
  int someChildProperty1, someChildProperty2, ...;
}
```

and I'm trying to map a list of `Flattened` objects to a normalized nested list of parent/children, like so:

```
class Parent {
  int parentId;
  int someParentProperty1, ...;
  List<Child> children;
}

class Child {
  int childId;
  int someChildProperty1, ...;
}

List<Parent> map(List<Flattened> flattenedList);
```

Mapping the parent fields from the `Flattened` object to the `Parent` is easy, the trickier bit is accumulating all the `Child` objects from the `Flattened` list into each of the `Parent.children` fields. Is there an elegant way to do this with Mapstruct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to delegate all the logic to MapStruct, but for sure you can rely on it for mappings.

I'm not aware of a solution better than that:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING, injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface MyMapper {

    MyMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);

    default List<Parent> map(List<Flattened> flattenedList) {
        Map<String, List<Flattened>> groupedFlattened = flattenedList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Flattened::getParentId));

        return groupedFlattened.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
            List<Flattened> flattenedChildren = entry.getValue();
            return mapFlattenedToParent(flattenedChildren.get(0), flattenedChildren);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Named("mapFlattenedToParent")
    @Mapping(target = "children", source = "flattenedChildren", qualifiedByName = "mapFlattenedToChildren")
    Parent mapFlattenedToParent(Flattened flattened, List<Flattened> flattenedChildren);

    @Named("mapFlattenedToChildren")
    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "mapFlattenedToChild")
    List<Child> mapFlattenedToChildren(List<Flattened> flattenedList);

    @Named("mapFlattenedToChild")
    Child mapFlattenedToChild(Flattened flattened);

}
```

You can find a test case on my GitHub: [MappingAFlattenedParentChildListTest.java](https://github.com/paulmarcelinbejan/Training/blob/develop/stack-overflow/src/test/java/com/paulmarcelinbejan/training/stackoverflow/mapstruct/custommapping/Q8/MappingAFlattenedParentChildListTest.java)